# How to set the style of TextInputEditText in styles.xml

Tags: android

I am using `TextInputEditText` in my registration screen. I am able to set the style of floating label. I want to set the custom font on hint and text of `TextInputEditText` using style. Does anyone know whats way of it ?

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_registration_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/default_view_padding_right_8dp"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/default_view_padding_left_8dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorSecondaryText"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.InputLayoutStyle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview_registration_title">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/registration_name"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.InputLayoutStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/lato_light</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.TextView</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Button</item>
</style>
```

I want to set style for entire application.

Comment: You can add this style as a theme in TextInputLayout in XML .

Comment: For that I have to add to each TextInputLayout

Comment: Yes. In this case you have to do this

Comment: I want it should be managed by styles.xml only as like I did for `TextView`

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 23):

Old question but worth to answer.

Just set the "textInputStyle" to style the **TextInputLayouts** and "editTextStyle" to style the **TextInputEditTexts** in your app theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.TextView</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Button</item>
    <item name="textInputStyle">
        @style/MyCustomTextInputStyle
    </item>
    <item name="editTextStyle">
        @style/MyCustomEditTextStyle
    </item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTextInputStyle" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorSecondaryText</item>
    <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/any_style_you_may_want"</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomEditTextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/lato_light</item>
</style>
```

This will apply the same style to **all** TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText in you application.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. How does one know that 'textInputStyle' etc. exist and what they are meant for?

Comment: and if you want to apply customized style to just one specific TextInputEditText, what you do is add `style="@style/MyCustomTextInputStyle"` to the `TextInputLayout`